# FireFox Service Worker appears to be restarting, but not if being debugged

Tags: firefox, service-worker

We have a web application that has a Javascript Service Worker. The service worker contains some state that is stored to a Javascript variable.

In Chrome everything works as expected - the service worker is created, the state can be set and then reliably retrieved later. The state is held for the duration of the session.

In Firefox the service worker is created and the state can be retrieved for a while. Then it appears the service worker is restarted or the state is lost. When pages attempt to get the state from the service worker it returns the default value.

I've added extra console logging into the service worker for when it is started and when the state is accessed/updated. These logs appear in Chrome as expected but don't appear in the main Firefox console window. When I open the service worker debugger I can see the logs in there, but when the service worker debugger window is running the problem doesn't occur. It seems that the debugger window prevents the problem - which is good, but not a solution I can expect of users!

How can I determine why the service worker is restarting or the state is being lost?

How can I get visibility of what is happening to the state in a normal Firefox window without the debugger window which appears to change the behaviour?

Ultimately the state will be able to be retrieved from another location as the service worker isn't a reliable place to store this, but I'd still like to understand why this is happening and if there is any way to prevent/reduce the loss of state.